# Page-by output. LINQ, Skip() and Take()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, output

I get two items if do like this:

```cs
private int page = 0;
private int size = 2;

List<ContractTableRow> rows =
    (from c in model.Contracts
     join w in model.Workers on c.Worker equals w.Id
     where c.Worker == w.Id
     select new ContractTableRow
     {
        ...
     })
     .Skip(page * size)
     .Take(size)
     .ToList();
```

I get all items if I do:

```cs
List<ContractTableRow> rows =
      (from c in model.Contracts
       .Skip(page * size)
       .Take(size)
       join w in model.Workers on c.Worker equals w.Id
       where c.Worker == w.Id
       select new ContractTableRow
       {
          ...
       })
       .ToList();
```

Why doesn't the second code gives two elements?

What is the sequence of the first code? First `select` all elements with `new ContractTableRow` and then `skip`, `take`? Or initially `skip`, `take` and then `select`?

I need this to create a page-by output of records from the database. Is it right to implement it this way?

Comment: You are taking 2 Contracts, then joining them with Workers, so you will get all Workers with these 2 Contracts, which can be more than two unless there is a one-to-one corrolation

Comment: We can't tell you whether it's "right" to do it that way. There are many factors which can't be answered in Stack Overflow's limited space. If it works, and you're not finding any performance or security problems with it, then it's as "right" as it gets...

Comment: If  you want to do a page-by-page then do a Select((row, index) => new {row = row, index = index}).GroupBy(x => x.index/ size)

Comment: The order matters a lot. Your two queries are not the same. In the 2nd one you are limiting Contracts by the `skip` and `take` and applying the rest of the criteria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do this is, first get rid of the `join` and use Navigation properties, then the right order is IQueryable.OrderBy.[ThenBy.]Skip.Take.Select.  And you must provide an OrderBy that completely orders the results, or else your pages can have gaps and overlaps.

```
List<ContractTableRow> rows =
       db.Contracts
         .OrderBy( r => r.Id )
         .Skip(page * size)
         .Take(size)
         .Select( c => new ContractTableRow()
           {
              c.Id,
              c.Worker.Name...
           })
         .ToList();
```

Comment: If with `select new ContractTableRow` - don't compiled. Works  -  `.Select(c => new ContractTableRow{...})`